# How to put the fetched data in the input field - AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Im trying to live search or filter some data in my database using **AJAX**, I used the `oninput` event to trigger the function. But it's not working, can someone help me to find what's wrong in my code? Im just a beginner in ajax.

Here's my input field,

```
   <div class="form-group">
               <label for="stud_num">Student Number</label>
                <input type="text" name="stud_num" class="form-control stud_num" oninput="loadinfo()" id="stud_num" placeholder="Student Number" style="max-width:150px;" required>
        </div>
```

here's my function,

```
  function loadinfo(){
    var stud = $("#stud_num").val();
    $.ajax({
      url:'getrecords.php',
      method:'POST',
      data:{
        "loadinfo": 1,
        "stud": stud,
      },
      success: function(data){
        $('#firstname').val(data.firstname);
      }
    });
  }
```

here the php code,

```
   if(isset($_POST['loadinfo'])){
    $stud = $_POST['stud'];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM studmast WHERE stud_no ='$stud'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

       while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                  $data[] = array(
                        'lastname' => $row['lastname'],
                        'firstname' => $row['firstname'],
                        'midname' => $row['middlename']
                        );
            }
            echo $data;
   }
```

Comment: You can't echo an array directly -> `echo $data;`. Use [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) -> `echo json_encode($data);`.

Comment: do i need to put in the ajax the **dataType: 'json',** ?

Comment: You can, but not completely necessary as jQuery does and `Intelligent Guess` -> [*If none is specified, jQuery will try to infer it based on the MIME type of the response*](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Comment: have you checked your browser developer tools to see if the ajax call in invoked?

Comment: @sean is this what are you talking about `XHR finished loading: POST "http://localhost/studentportal/getrecords.php".` ?

Comment: Yes. You should be able to see the `Form Data` that was sent, and a `Response`.

Comment: Where can i see that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't echo a php array...you need to send a data format that can easily be consumed by client and the most common nowadays is json.

Use [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to convert

Try

```
echo json_encode($data);
```

And make sure to set the `dataType:'json` in `$.ajax`

Comment: Still not working, Im trying do a live search. Is **oninput** event is wrong approach? I tried to change it to `json_encode` already.

Comment: try using `onchange` or use a key event and add an error handler to the ajax. Inspect actual request in browser dev tools network to see if it is made, what th status is, and what is sent/received is what is expected

Comment: When i remove the `.firstname` in the **data.firstname** the input has a value but its `[object Object]`.

Comment: You are receiving an array of objects. If db query is only going to be one row then return a single object and not array of objects, otherwise you would need to iterate array and do something with each object

Comment: For quick test try `$('#firstname').val(data[0].firstname);`

Comment: Because you create nested array in php, which will translate to an array of objects when parsed from json, even if it's only one object in that array

Answer (score 0):

Because I cannot reply to comments yet.. @nethken as others have stated, use json_encode. Please ensure that data is being posted to the php file in question. You can confirm this by debugging the code in developer tools. Either step through the code or alert the value before sending (javascript client-side debugging).

Next, I would var_dump($_POST['stud']) in your php file, this will confirm whether the value is getting there or not. You can see the data by going to the network traffic in your developer tools and selecting preview of the php file. If you have xDebug you can simply step through the code to debug, I'll assume you do not have it setup.